# What is the maximum file size upload limit in Internet Explorer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mongrel

In my Rails application I am able to upload only up to 1.5GB when using Internet Explorer, but when I use Chrome I am able to upload 10GB without a problem. Why is this? I am running Mongrel as my web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look at the http-header:

> Content-Length: -1618952669

The value should be the file-size in byte (never a negative-value).

Regarding this Web-Page http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm
There is a limit within the browser ~2.0GB. Files larger than this may produce an integer-overflow.

Comment: Thansk Ascomae is there any way to allow IE to upload file larger than 2gb or more??Means can 64 bit IE can help me??

Comment: It may be with a 64-bit version of IE, but I don't know. But you can try it an look into the http-header.

Comment: If you know more about that large uploads, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old thread, but just to help others looking for info about IE upload limits

- Version           Upload          Download
- IE7             2gb                4gb
- IE8                      2gb               17,592GB
- IE9, 10           4gb                17,592GB

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx

Comment: Hello and welcome.  It's generally considered good form here to post the relevant information extracted from any links, and then back that information up with the links.